# Umbraco: Must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.

Tags: razor, umbraco, partial, umbraco6

I am running Umbraco 6.0.7 and trying to make a partial view work in a template, but get the error

> The view at '~/Views/Partials/kb.cshtml' must derive from
>   WebViewPage, or WebViewPage.

I am unsure how to fix this - so any help is appreciated.

The template:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
Layout = "Site.cshtml";    
}
<div>
 @Html.Partial("kb")
</div>
```

The Partial view (kb.cshtml):

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{
    var parent = Model.AncestorOrSelf(2);
    if (parent != null) { 
        traverse(parent,2,3);
    }
}

@helper traverse(dynamic parent,int startLevel,int finishLevel) {

    <ul>

        foreach (var item in parent.Children.Where("umbracoNaviHide!=true")) {

            var selected = (Array.IndexOf(Model.Path.Split(','), item.Id.ToString()) >= 0 ? " class=\"selected\"" : "");

            <li >
                <a href="item.Url">item.Name</a>
                if (selected !="" && item.Level <= 3)  { 
                    traverse(item,2,3)
                }

            </li>
        }

    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the top two lines from kb.cshtml:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
```

and replace them with:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
```

This is no different to implementing a standard MVC partial that inherits its model from the parent view.

There is a lot of documentation at [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org) that I seriously suggest you read through as this will help massively with things like this.

Comment: Thanks :) I looked through our.umbraco.org - but failed to find this info.